Add columns to dataframe from a dictionary
There are many answers out there to this question, but I couldn't find one that applies to my case.
I have a dataframe that contains ID's:
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]})

Now, I query a REST API for each ID's to get additional attributes that are returned to me as a dictionary:
{"id": 0, "values": {"first_name": "Bob", "last_name": "Smith"}}

What I want is to add the content of values as additional columns to the matching row of the dataframe.
An important point is that, at each iteration, I may get different attributes, so I don't know how many columns will be added in the end, or even their names. So, sometimes I need to add a column (which I would do with pd.concat), but sometimes I need to set the value to an existing one.



id
first_name
last_name
something
something_else




0
Bob
Smith




…






4







Any thought?

I agree there are many ways out there to do this. You can do it this way with List Comprehension approach which will be Faster I guess, and will handle dynamic columns well.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]})

# Simulated API response
def get_api_data(id):
    data = {
        0: {"first_name": "Bob", "last_name": "Smith"},
        1: {"first_name": "Alice", "something": "extra"},
        2: {"last_name": "Jones", "something_else": "value"},
        3: {"first_name": "Charlie", "age": 30},
        4: {}  # No data available for this ID
    }
    return data.get(id, {})

def update_dataframe(df):
    all_columns = set()
    data_list = []
    
    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        api_data = get_api_data(row['id'])
        all_columns.update(api_data.keys())
        row_data = row.to_dict()
        row_data.update(api_data)
        data_list.append(row_data)
    
    result_df = pd.DataFrame(data_list, columns=list(all_columns) + list(df.columns))
    
    return result_df

updated_df = update_dataframe(df)
print(updated_df)

Output:
   id first_name last_name something something_else   age
0   0        Bob     Smith       NaN            NaN   NaN
1   1      Alice       NaN     extra            NaN   NaN
2   2        NaN     Jones       NaN          value   NaN
3   3    Charlie       NaN       NaN            NaN  30.0
4   4        NaN       NaN       NaN            NaN   NaN


Code
your example
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]})
data = {"id": 0, "values": {"first_name": "Bob", "last_name": "Smith"}}

code
# make data dict to dataframe (For multiple dict, use concat)
d = pd.json_normalize(data)

# merge
out = df.merge(d, how='left')

out:
   id values.first_name values.last_name
0   0               Bob            Smith
1   1               NaN              NaN
2   2               NaN              NaN
3   3               NaN              NaN
4   4               NaN              NaN

If you want to remove value. from a column name, you can use the rename function or the str.replace function.

Another possible solution, whose steps are:

First, it converts the dictionary d into a dataframe using pd.DataFrame.

Then, it resets the index of this dataframe with reset_index.

Next, it pivots the dataframe using pivot to reshape it, setting id as the index, values as the values, and index as the columns.

After pivoting, it resets the index again and removes the axis name with rename_axis.

Finally, it merges this transformed dataframe with the original dataframe df on the id column using merge.


df.merge(
    pd.DataFrame(d).reset_index()
    .pivot(index='id', values='values', columns='index')
    .reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1), on='id', how='left')

Output:
   id first_name last_name
0   0        Bob     Smith
1   1        NaN       NaN
2   2        NaN       NaN
3   3        NaN       NaN
4   4        NaN       NaN

